# Receiving windows push notification in a desktop app targeted for windows 7, 8 and 10

Tags: push-notification, uwp, desktop-bridge

I have a windows desktop application for which we have existing client using it on windows 7, 8 and 10. Now I want to register this application to receive windows push notifications from a cloud service.

- MSDN says  that the `CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync` API for asking channel URI is only available in windows uwp applications.
- I read regarding desktop bridge technology. But, it says that then the converted appx bundle should have minimum target version Windows 10.0, build 14393i.e. anniversary update. But we have clients using our application on Windows 7 and 8 too.
- We thought that we could have a no-GUI windows uwp application running on win 7 and 8 like a service, and give us the messages we received from cloud service by some IPC mechanism. And then we can launch that uwp application by its AUMID when client starts our application. But, that also seems impossible as there is no option to have a uwp command line application, also it is not possible to have win uwp app running and displaying its icon in windows tray.

So, is it possible to register for push notification in a desktop application targeted for windows 7 and 8?

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you make your question shorter and clearer, you'll be more likely to get useful answers. I will try to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not want to convert your desktop application to UWP app, you would not be able to use this API. The push notification relevant functions are the new features in universal windows platform. It's not available in the old windows version. So, it's impossible.